# How is 百にも足らぬ used here?

Tags: meaning, auxiliary-ず

How is 百にも足らぬ used here?

> 「算え｛かぞえ｝十九の若さで御供頭の大役を仰せつかるとは、冥加｛みょうが｝な話よのう」背戸｛せど｝の畑から戻ってきた叔父は、野良着のまま囲炉裏端に座りこむと、まるきり他人事のように言った。
>
> 「お言葉ではございますが叔父上、冥加と申されるのもいかがなものかと」
>
> 一路｛いちろ｝は憮然として抗った。武士だか百姓だかもわからぬ叔父は、**百にも足らぬ**御家来衆の典型である。しかし頼りになる親類がほかにいないのでは仕様がなかった。

Is it 取るに足らない, [成句](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%99%BE%E8%B6%B3%E3%82%89%E3%81%AC) sense

Or 百（の数）にも足らない（達しない）, literal sense?

Or something else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

足{た}る in the phrases you mention refers to *"being enough, being sufficient (to do something, to be something)"*.  取るに足らない could be understood literally as *"insufficient"* (足らない) *"to / for taking"* (取るに) → by extension, *"not worth picking up → not worth the bother, insignificant"*.  Meanwhile, 百にも足らぬ would be *"insufficient"* (足らぬ) *"to / for even a hundred"* (百にも) → *"not even a hundred, not quite a hundred"*: as you note, 数に達しない in the literal sense.